# errores y dudas con react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Estoy en un proyecto y me pidieron usar `react`, sinceramente la documentación de react te deja muchísimas dudas, a mi parecer esta muy mal redactada y no puede entender varias cosas; la primera es que en la documentación de react casi siempre se habla de la programación funcional y no se habla mucho del uso de clases y cuando quiero agregar distintos estilos en una clase usando `makeStyles` no se muy bien donde iniciar la variable clases y se me arma un *quilombo*, en este momento al hacer uso de `Axios`, quiero mostrar por consola el resultado de la petición pero se me traba la pc ya que se genera un bucle y no deja de mostrar en consola lo que recibió la petición, este es mi componente con la consulta

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { makeStyles, createStyles, Theme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import axios, {AxiosResponse, AxiosError} from 'axios'


//COMPONENTES
import Port from './port'

//CSS PERSONALIZADO
import './css/index.css'

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
  aside: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    overflow: 'auto'
   }
 }),
);

axios.get("http://localhost:8080/api/userData")
  .then((res: AxiosResponse)=>{
    console.log(res.data)
  })
  .catch((err: AxiosError)=>{
    console.log(err.response)
  })
  .finally(()=>{
    
  })

  export default function Aside(props: any) {

     const [user,setUser] = useState({})


   const classes = useStyles()
   return (
    <aside className={classes.aside}>
        <Port user={user}/>
    </aside>
)
}
```

Cual es la mejor manera de manejar las petición? fuera de la función o dentro? es mejor si creo una carpeta service y traer las peticiones desde ahí? es factible usar rxjs en react? y mi ultima pregunta es la siguiente,
mi componente `Port` usa funciones, supongamos que yo a ese componente lo cree con clase, como tengo que hacer para poder acceder a esa propiedad? es mi mayor duda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**cual es la mejor manera de manejar las peticion? fuera de la funcion o dentro?**

Existen métodos definidos por react para ciertas tareas como: `componentDidMount` en componentes y `useEffect` en funciones, ambos se ejecutan inmediatamente después de renderizar el componente. Dicha función deberia estar dentro de la función(valga la redundancia), ej:

```
export default function Aside(props: any) {
   const [user,setUser] = useState({})
   useEffect(() => {
     //ejecutar axios aqui.
     // es casi igual a componentDidMount con la diferencia que tambien funciona como componentDidUpdate
   });
   
   const classes = useStyles()
   return (
     <aside className={classes.aside}>
        <Port user={user}/>
     </aside>
   )
}
```

**es mejor si creo una carpeta service y traer las peticiones desde ahi? es factible usar rxjs en react?**

React solo es una "libreria"-"framework" de javascript, y cualquier servicie, librería y/o función funcionan de maravilla si sabes de javascript.

**mi componente Port usa funciones, supongamos que yo a ese componente lo cree con clase, como tengo que hacer para poder acceder a esa propiedad?**

No se entiende bien esta pregunta, pero el acceso a propiedades entre componentes es de `padre` a `hijo`. Es decir un padre puede enviarle valores de propiedad a un hijo y el padre siempre tendrá acceso dicho valor.

Lo que no existe es que un hijo comunique un valor de propiedad a un padre. aunque siempre puedes tener un `callback` para hacer un poco de trampa.

*Hasta aqui tus preguntas*

Ahora no concuerdo con: `la documentacion de react te deja muchisimas dudas`, al contrario explica toda su funcionalidad paso a paso y con ejemplos muy claros, ademas de existir su versión en español. Leelo detenidamente y veras lo facil que es react.